# How to express a number as a sum of consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sequences

I have an array which contains numbers in sorted order. 
I am given a number and asked to express it as a sum of consecutive numbers in the array. How do I do that?

For example, consider an array

```
arr={2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41}
```

and a number, say 41. 
It can be expressed as the following

```
2+3+5+7+11+13
```

In case of a number 15, it should be expressed as

```
3+5+7
```

I need an algorithm/code to efficiently find all such values.

Comment: What do you mean by 'all such values'? Do you mean that you want all solutions, if there is more than one possible way to get the given number?

Comment: Here is a hint: It can be done in `O(n)`. Show us your code or explain where you got suck.

Comment: I've tried finding the sum of two consecutive elements in the array and storing it in another array. That way, I’ll be able to find out all the numbers that are being expressed as the sum of two consecutive numbers. In that case, if the number of consecutive numbers is not known, it is very difficult to express the number, like in case of 41.

Comment: I mean, an algorithm to find out how to express a number as sum of values in an array @MrSmith42

Answer (score 0):

let `x` be the number we search the summation for:

```
arr={2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41}  
l=0  // index from where to start sum up (l left)  
r=0  // index until where to sum up (r right) 

label:
  sum=arr[l]+...arr[r]
  if(sum==x)
    return (l,r);
  if(sum<x)
    r++
  if(sum>x)
    l++
goto label
```

You need to add some conditions to handle cases when it is not possible to find a sum.

```
Visually explained example: x=36
{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41} 
()                sum = 2      l=0 r=0
(   )             sum = 5      l=0 r=1
(     )           sum = 10     l=0 r=2
(       )         sum = 17     l=0 r=3
(          )      sum = 28     l=0 r=4
(             )   sum = 41     l=0 r=5
  (           )   sum = 39     l=1 r=5
    (         )   sum = 36     l=2 r=5  -> return (2,5)

Result arr[2]+...+arr[5] = 36
```

Comment: I think you need to add a condition to break for numbers that can't be express by a sum of consecutive numbers like 6, if(l>r) break;

Comment: @AnotherGeek: That's what I mean by the sentence: 'You need to add some conditions to handle cases when it is not possible to find a sum.'